# If f: $[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and uniformly continuous in $[k,\infty]$, then it's uniformly continuous in $[0,\infty]$.

Tags: calculus

Let f: $[0,\infty]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. Prove that, if f is uniformly continuous in $[k,\infty]$ for some k, then f is uniformly continuous in $[0,\infty]$ I don´t know how to do this, I would appreciate your help

(S.A. Understanding Analysis. pp 119 question 4.4.8)

Comment: What is the definition of continuity at $\infty$? Or did you mean $[0, \infty)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: It's very relevant that $[0, k]$ is compact, and every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. Can you combine uniform continuity on $[0, k]$ with uniform continuity on $[k, \infty)$?

Comment: I think that first I need to prove that if f is continuous in $[0,k]$ then is uniformly continuous in $[0,k]$

Comment: @DavidHernandez You're given that $f$ is continuous on a set containing $[0, k]$.